# Macro to convert array to struct

Tags: c

I have the following requirement. Can I do it using macro?

Here is an array `abc_xyz[pqr]` which needs to be renamed as `abc[pqr].xyz`, 
maybe something like

```
#define abc_xyz[pqr] abc[pqr].xyz
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Why do you need the "renaming"? Wouldn't it be simpler (and clearer to all readers of the code) if you use the correct variant in the first place?

Comment: Also, macros can't have the symbols `[` or `]` in them. It might be possible using some kind of function-like macro though, but I still recommend against it (macros tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain).

Comment: To be clear, macro *names* cannot have the symbols `[` or `]` in them.  They follow the same rules as other identifiers.

Comment: Additionally, macros cannot extract pieces of tokens.  That is, there is no way to write a general purpose macro that extracts the pieces `abc` and `xyz` from tokens of the form `abc_xyz`.  You can approach that kind of thing with macros aimed at *specific* identifiers, but not generically.